# Change dd command in evil mode to not write to clipboard

Tags: evil, clipboard

I would like to use normal modes commands like `d` `c` `x` etc without the content being copied to clipboard.

I want to make emacs so that only `y` command will write anything to the clipboard. Other commands like `d` should only delete the content without writing anything to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

`(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill nil)`

Separating the clipboard and kill-ring is more efficient for my workflow, for clipboard, I use https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip API `simpleclip-set-content` and `simpleclip-get-content`

Answer (score 0):

If you do `C-h k d` you'll see that <kbd>d</kbd> is bounded to `evil-delete`, [so](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc13):

```el
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "dd" 'my/very-special-evil-delete)
```

should do the work. There's a "`/dev/null`-ish" (`blackhole`) register in vim which probably `evil` mocks.

Answer (score 0):

This adds an advice around evil stuff to drop it to `_` register.

```
(defun meain/evil-delete-advice (orig-fn beg end &optional type _ &rest args)
    "Make d, c, x to not write to clipboard."
    (apply orig-fn beg end type ?_ args))
(advice-add 'evil-delete :around 'meain/evil-delete-advice)
(advice-add 'evil-change :around 'meain/evil-delete-advice)
```